# Microsoft Partner Center: enroll in microsoft edge with professional email

Tags: microsoft-edge-extension

Following this doc: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/publish/create-dev-account I](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/publish/create-dev-account%C2%A0I) understand I cannot use a professional email address to enroll in the edge program in the partner center. Question is how can I publish a edge extension for my company?

I created a github account linked to the email but it did not work better.

I manage to enroll with a personal account but in this case the partner center is not linked to the one of my company.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not ask their developer support for help?

Comment: hey @NicoHaase thanks for the comment, because there is no way to contact them about this topic, I tried many support channel with them but I never end up in something they support :(